# Directory.Exists() Cannot find network directory if application launched on Windows logon

Tags: c#, caching, windows-8.1, shared-directory

I have an application which checks for the existence of a network folder on startup. If it doesn't find the network folder, then it keeps polling every second until it does, and then does the processing proper.

```
Logger.Instance.LogDebug("Checking for network location: |" + Settings.Instance.TransferNetworkLocation + "|");

if (Directory.Exists(Settings.Instance.TransferNetworkLocation))
{
     // Do the stuff

}
else
{
    Logger.Instance.LogDebug("Couldn't find the network location!");
    IsNetworkLocationAvailable = false;
    DisplayNetworkWarning = true;
    return;
}
```

(`Settings.Instance.TransferNetworkLocation` has a value like `\\MYHOST-PC12345\My Shared Location\`)

Now sometimes the network won't be available, in which case it will just keep polling until it becomes available. And that all works fine

*Except:*

When the application is set to launch on Windows startup! Now of course the network is not connected at startup, and it takes a few seconds for the network to connect. So I expect it to fail (i.e. return `false`) for a while.

But it continues to poll and even after the network connection is established and the user can go into Windows Explorer and browse to that shared folder, but the call to `Directory.Exists()` continues to return `false` and never realises that the folder now exists.

I have noticed from the logging you can see in that code, the first time it checks for the network folder, it takes some time to fail - I'm assuming it's waiting for the time-out. But every other time it checks, it doesn't time take this long, and instantaneously responds that the folder doesn't exist.

Is there some sort of caching of the failure to find this location? If so, is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: Rather than diving into the specifics of that and possibly ending up in the belly of the network redirector with no way of getting out, I suggest using [`NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable) and [`NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkavailabilitychanged) before you start polling for the path, even if it technically seems redundant. (Also, polling every *second* seems excessive.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Unfortunately, `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` seems to return true the moment the application starts... Then I am back into the same position as above.

Comment: Extract the server, ping it. (OK, it's getting a little more complicated now, also, ping might be firewalled when SMB is not.) Or, the ultimate in low-tech solutions: if you detect the system uptime is very low (`Environment.TickCount`), sleep for a while before you start your polling barrage. (There are probably more robust approaches for detecting the system's "sort of" stable now, I forget what they are. Services have a "delayed start" startup type, for example.)

Comment: Oh, it occurs to me that what might be cached is a negative DNS response/timeout (although that ought to be per-system, not leave only your process with no access -- but the ways of NetBIOS are inscrutable). There's not much you can (or should) do to influence this in your own application, though, as manipulating that cache is a privileged operation. If that's what's tripping things up, it should go away after 5 minutes (the default expiration of a negative cache entry). That may be too long for your purposes, but at least it would help narrow things down.

Comment: "Set to launch at Windows startup" is a little vague, depending on what exactly you mean it may be that application isn't running in the same logon session as Explorer.  You can double-check this using Process Monitor, which is available from the MS web site.  The Logon Session for a process is shown in the Security tab of the Properties window.  You're looking for a longish hexadecimal number, e..g, `2e3c7a8`.